# ValueError showing up while using tensorflow's keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, valueerror

I am new to to machine learning and am trying a simple program with keras. When I run the following code, I get an error saying "ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 784 but received input with shape [32, 28, 28]". Could someone help me with this? I am trying to follow along with this video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tjsHSIG8I08, but it doesnt seem to work. Thanks in advance!

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(784,)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)

loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)
print('Accuracy', accuracy)

scores = model.predict(test_images[0:1])
print(np.argmax(scores))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem come from `input_shape=(784,)`. First you need to understand how input dimension works. Input data must follow this dimension (number of sample, input dimension), so in your case with (32, 28, 28) which is a mnist datasets dimension of (28 X 28) with number of sample equal to 32. Therefore, you must change to `input_shape=(28,28)` and you are good to go.

Comment: try replace (28, 28) with (32, 28, 28)